# SQL 3 table structure ascending order

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

I have 3 tables in my database, “Doctors”, “Workers”, “Works”, I need to store the differentiated price list as well, but I don’t know what would be the perfect solution or placement for them. (I’m writing a basic program for storing the prices for works for a dental company, and listing them)
I know the price placement would be great inside any of these tables, if I don’t need to rearrange the doctor or work list every time the admin adds a new item to the work table or adds a new doctor to the list.

So in short: what’s the best placement of price list in a database, if I have to rearrange the works by ascending order.

For example: I store 3 doctors (d1,d2,d3), and 1 worker (w1), I have works (a,b,c,...) all the works have DIFFERENT prices for DIFFERENT doctors, (and workers). Now I place an a2 work inside works table, I have to rearrange it in ascending order.
Do I need an entirely new structure for database? Any tips? Thx

Already tried to place the price list inside doctors and workers, but the problem is, I have to get them rearrange every time someone adds a new work.

The SQL code wouldn’t make anything easier, I think the example above a better way to show the problem.

Comment: You shouldnt have to re-arrange anything in the database, use the SQL code to sort it by whatever criteria you need when returning the data.

Comment: Strore data "as is". Query the data as you want. Because data will change.

Comment: This is entirely too vague to answer at the moment. You need to provide details like the current table structure, your proposed changes and what you are trying to do. As is sits right now I can't comprehend what you are asking or what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I'd make a change to your existing tables to abstract doctors and workers into `Employees` and add a fourth table to hold the price for each employee and service (or work as you called it). Here's how I'd do it:

```
CREATE TABLE [Employees] (
    [EmployeeId] int,
    [Name] varchar(100),
    [RoleId] int
)

CREATE TABLE [Roles] (
    [RoleId] int,
    [Name] varchar(100)
)

CREATE TABLE [Services] (
    [ServiceId] int,
    [Name] varchar(100)
)

CREATE TABLE [Employees_Services] (
    [EmployeeId] int,
    [ServiceId] int,
    [Price] decimal(19,4)
)
```

**Employees** would have a row for each person in the organization.

**Roles** would contain, based on your example, two rows, one for Doctor and one for Worker.

**Services** would contain a row for each type of work that is done by any employee.

**Employees_Services** would hold a row for each employee and service that they can provide and their price for that service.

This way each employee can have their own price for each service, and adding or removing employees, roles, or services wouldn't require any rearranging. It also gives you the added benefit of being able to control which employee is able to provide each service. E.g. an employee other than a Doctor probably shouldn't be able to provide surgery.

I would also create foreign key constraints between the related columns, I think that part is self-explanatory, but let me know if you need help.